# Feasibility of The Absorbic Bomb from The Killing Star

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapon-mass-destruction

I have come across a weapon by The Killing Star, which is called the Absorbic Bomb.

Apparently, it reverses the formula E = mc^2, of how matter is converted to energy during standard nuclear blasts, such that the bomb in question insteads convert energy to matter, m = E/c^2, essentially the inverse of a nuclear weapon.

Precisely, after the explosion, lots of energy is sucked up from the blast radius and converted into a bit of matter. Ground Zero would suddenly be at zero Kelvin, with a bit of extra dust floating in the air.

The author of The Killing Star, Pellegrino and Zebrowski, said that it could be possible, but requires a giant amount of magnetic monopoles, as stated here:

“The battle within the Sun is, of course, pure ﬁction, constrained only by the hard facts of magnetic ﬁeld projection, solar physics, and orbital mechanics. The absorbic bomb, through which energy can be converted instantaneously into matter (the inverse of a conventional nuclear explosion) does not yet exist, and may never exist unless, according to Powell and Pellegrino, a sufficient number of magnetic monopoles can be found, or created in atomic accelerators and brought together in just the right geometry to produce … Well, perhaps we're all better off not dwelling on how to create this particular nightmare.”

I wonder if such is possible by any means, especially through the use of monopoles as they have claimed.

Also, the main site to learn more about The Absorbic Bomb.

http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunexotic.php#id--Absorbic_Bomb

PS If Monopoles do not work, then I wonder if there is any other way for this to be possible.

Comment: There is symmetry in the math, but this crosses a line that we've not figured out how to traverse yet. How is this about building a world?

Comment: @WeareMonica. I think OP is trying to find a more powerful alternative to nukes to spice up his world.

Comment: I've seen lot of other stuff involving monopoles, but no other references to easy energy-to-matter conversion in that way. It sounds exceedingly thermodynamically dubious, though pretty nifty as a fictional device.

Comment: Magnetic monopoles and the "hard science" tag are a tough order.

Comment: with hard science tag you are going to get a solid 0 answer. There is no research conducted on such a device, so it will impossible to satisfy the requirement of hard science, which is providing references, citations and empirical evidences.

Comment: I'd really rather folks not be quick to question whether or not an inquiry here is involved in building a world (and hence fit for worldbuilding.SE), and perhaps instead _err_ on the side of the cautionary _assumption_ that it does.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated perhaps cast your eye over the list of questions that the OP has asked in the past.

Comment: Well, if you don't mind not being able to extract that energy/matter from inside, I promise not to object calling a black hole an Absorbic Bomb.

The idea that may work (with some handwaving) is to curve the spacetime in such a way that the energy meanders long enough inside to create matter by collision and condense it. May take a while to get your matter at the output end of the contraption.

Answer (score 1):

While there are experiments describing behavior that is consistent with magnetic monopoles, Maxwell’s equations — our fundamental theory of Electromagnetism — explicitly states that there are no magnetic monopoles.

Your absorbic bomb might work by raising the temperature of a small region of the star to conditions nearer to moments after the big bang ( 1-100 kEv) which seems contradictory to your goal.  That region will expand — cause that’s what hot things do — and will elevate the temperature of the plasma at the boundary of the expansion.  The expansion will continue until its energy is back to equilibrium with the rest of the star.

As the super-super-mega-heated plasma — which is no long a plasma — cools down to less than 100 eV and nucleosynthesis starts. You end up with a bunch of hydrogen atoms and helium atoms.

These took the place of a bunch of heavy elements, so the star’s confinement reduces because its gravity decreases.  And, these light elements heat and fuse, increasing the star’s output.  It becomes imbalanced — less confinement and greater expansion — and the star goes nova.

Comment: On [magnetic monopoles break Maxwell's Equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22018/225215).